# 22.04 Mobile broadband LTE SIM modem connected but can't ping IP

Tags: networking, network-manager, modem

The only strange thing that I can see is link/none

```
mmcli -m 0
  ----------------------------------
  General  |                   path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
           |              device id: xxx
  ----------------------------------
  Hardware |           manufacturer: QUALCOMM INCORPORATED
           |                  model: QUECTEL Mobile Broadband Module
           |      firmware revision: EC25
           |         carrier config: default
           |           h/w revision: 10000
           |              supported: gsm-umts, lte
           |                current: gsm-umts, lte
           |           equipment id: xxx
  ----------------------------------
  System   |                 device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5
           |                drivers: option, qmi_wwan
           |                 plugin: quectel
           |           primary port: cdc-wdm3
           |                  ports: cdc-wdm3 (qmi), ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB1 (gps), 
           |                         ttyUSB2 (at), ttyUSB3 (at), wwx26abba8a821e (net)
  ----------------------------------
  Status   |                   lock: sim-pin2
           |         unlock retries: sim-pin (3), sim-puk (10), sim-pin2 (3), sim-puk2 (10)
           |                  state: connected
           |            power state: on
           |            access tech: lte
           |         signal quality: 47% (cached)
  ----------------------------------
  Modes    |              supported: allowed: 2g; preferred: none
           |                         allowed: 3g; preferred: none
           |                         allowed: 4g; preferred: none
           |                         allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 3g
           |                         allowed: 2g, 3g; preferred: 2g
           |                         allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                         allowed: 2g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                         allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                         allowed: 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                         allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
           |                         allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 3g
           |                         allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 2g
           |                current: allowed: 2g, 3g, 4g; preferred: 4g
  ----------------------------------
  Bands    |              supported: egsm, dcs, utran-1, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, eutran-7, 
           |                         eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28, eutran-38, eutran-40, eutran-41
           |                current: egsm, dcs, utran-1, utran-8, eutran-1, eutran-3, eutran-7, 
           |                         eutran-8, eutran-20, eutran-28, eutran-38, eutran-40, eutran-41
  ----------------------------------
  IP       |              supported: ipv4, ipv6, ipv4v6
  ----------------------------------
  3GPP     |                   imei: xxx
           |          enabled locks: fixed-dialing
           |            operator id: 24002
           |           registration: home
  ----------------------------------
  3GPP EPS |   ue mode of operation: csps-2
           |    initial bearer path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/0
           | initial bearer ip type: ipv4v6
  ----------------------------------
  SIM      |       primary sim path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
  ----------------------------------
  Bearer   |                  paths: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/2
           |                         /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/1
ip addr
3: wwx26abba8a821e: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 100.108.xxx/28 brd 100.108.xxx scope global noprefixroute wwx26abba8a821e
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip route
default via 100.108.xxx dev wwx26abba8a821e proto static metric 700 
100.108.xxx/28 dev wwx26abba8a821e proto kernel scope link src 100.108.xxx metric 700 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wwx26abba8a821e scope link metric 1000

journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager
jul 18 15:54:57 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152497.6919] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.3605] device (cdc-wdm3): Activation: starting connection 'GSM connection 1' (c10b150e-0913-4907-8db4-be59772961b9)
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.3608] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="c10b150e-0913-4907-8db4-be59772961b9" name="GSM connection 1" pid=974 uid=1000 result="success"
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.3612] device (cdc-wdm3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.3617] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7000] device (cdc-wdm3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7004] device (cdc-wdm3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7007] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm3]: IPv4 static configuration:
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7008] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm3]:   address 100.108.xxx/28 brd* 100.108.xxx lft forever pref forever lifetime 2058-0[0,0] src wwan
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7008] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm3]:   gateway 100.108.xxx
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7008] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm3]:   DNS 80.251.201.177
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7008] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm3]:   DNS 80.251.201.178
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7008] modem-broadband[cdc-wdm3]:   MTU 1500
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7015] device (cdc-wdm3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7047] device (cdc-wdm3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7050] device (cdc-wdm3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7058] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7062] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7063] policy: set 'GSM connection 1' (wwx26abba8a821e) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7071] device (cdc-wdm3): Activation: successful, device activated.
jul 18 15:55:05 speakin-linux NetworkManager[562]: <info>  [1658152505.7076] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL

rfkill returns empty.
```

Comment: Not sure have you tried to remove pin request from your sim in your mobile?